# Polymer: how to ensure the browser is picking up the latest version of the code?

Tags: polymer

I've got a Polymer 1.0 app that's working well, but whenever I make an update the users are not seeing the latest version. They only do so when they force-refresh the browser, or after some time.

Is there a way to force the browser to always get the latest version?

I've added the following in index.html, to force the browser not to cache the page, but it doesn't seem to do much:

```
  <META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
  <META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1">
```

Any tip would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> Add hash chunk to file name when building your app.

Tools like webpack or gulp serve plugins which adds hash chunk to each bundled file so if there's any change in any component, filename changes and browser have to download the new version since it looks like as brand new file.

If not remember wrong, vulcanize do the job for polymer 1.